# How can i change the item to rectangle instead of circle

Tags: android, view

https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView

How can change the circle item in the wheel view to rectangle please help

Answer (score 1):

Try to change OvalShape() to RectShape() like-

```
    private Drawable createOvalDrawable(int color) {
        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
        return shapeDrawable;
    }
```

to

```
    private Drawable createOvalDrawable(int color) {
        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
        return shapeDrawable;
    }
```

in MainActivity.java